# Can I change param values in openmdao's solve_nonlinear

Tags: openmdao

I can set the unknowns and residuals in `components`' `solve_nonlinear` function. Can I also set the values of the params? Why or why not?

**Edit**

Here is my attempt at a "pure python" reader/writer component. My problem is that I can't read/write parameters from the top level.

```
$ cat test.py 
from openmdao.api import Component, Group, Problem

class reader():
   def __init__(self):
      self.file_to_read = 'test.in'
      self.file_data = 0
   def execute(self):
      dat = open(self.file_to_read, 'r')
      self.file_data = dat.read()

class writer():
   def  __init__(self):
      self.file_to_write = 'test.out'
      self.data = -99
   def execute(self):
      dat = open(self.file_to_write, 'w')
      dat.write(str(self.data))

class ReadWriteComp(Component):
   def __init__(self):
      super(ReadWriteComp, self).__init__()
      self.reader = reader()
      self.writer = writer()
      self.reader.execute()

   def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
      self.writer.data = self.reader.file_data
      self.writer.execute()

root = Group()
root.add('testio', ReadWriteComp())
prob = Problem(root)
prob.setup()
prob['testio.writer.file_to_write'] = 'newname' # "Variable 'testio.writer.file_to_write' not found."
prob.run()


$ cat test.in 
8
```

Comment: Hmm I've never tried it.  I suspect you'd end up destroying derivative information by doing this.

It sounds like your asking a question about a specific way to solve a more general problem.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @RobFalck I'm building a wrapper for a simulation code that is a group with read, write, and wrap components. I'm doing my best to emulate vartrees in 1.X.  https://github.com/WISDEM/AeroelasticSE/blob/turbsim_connection/src/AeroelasticSE/FAST_mdao/FST8_group.py#L78 My problem is that, in this "vartree" fst_vt object, the unknowns are the parameters: they have to be set by the reader and used by the writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Params are incoming values to a component. They are externally provided information. You can't/shouldn't change them because of this externality.

said another way: 
If you have incoming connections, then your param's value is defined by the output (source) of that upstream component. Changing your param would be like changing the output of that upstream component.

Comment: My problem is that my unknowns are the parameters. I want one component to read in a template file and set the parameters accordingly and for another component to use those parameters to write an input file. There are a lot of parameters, and I want to make this modular, as in only one set of things has to be edited to add items to the reading/writing process...

Answer (score 1):

I can't make a comment since my rep is too low, but this is more of a comment to the read/write components and not an answer to the question. I'd suggest to make the read/write and wrapper classes pure python and then only use openmdao at the top level with a component executing all three, perhaps with a group wrapped around if you need to parallelize cases.

Comment: I update my question to show my problem with this. I can't set write parameters from the top level. I'm used to reading the output the a vartree and writing the output with the same vartree. It looks like this is no longer an option and a more complex scheme is needed for setting write parameters from the top level.

Comment: The path to to the `testio` instance would be `prob.root.testio.writer.file_to_write`. And I guess some of the inputs to write will depend on outputs computed by upstream components, and for that I'd simply explicitly add these as params to your `ReadWriteComp`.